# why don't we need to pass in a function as an argument for this decorator?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a decorator here which takes a number `x` as a input and multiplies it by the result of the function `f_(*k)`. There is nothing wrong with the code it works perfectly. But the question is, when we use `sq(n)` how does this decorator take `sq(n)` and multiply it by 3? how does the decorator know to take the result of the function `sq(n)` and multiply it by 3. Because a parameter for a function was not given or in other words, how does it substitute `f_(*k)` for `sq(n)` because `sq(n)` was not given as an argument.

```
def multiply(x):
    def multiply_x(f):
        def f_(*k):
            return x*f(*k)
        return f_
    return multiply_x    





@multiply(3)
   def sq(n):
      return n*n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@decorator(arg)` is just a nice way to say `func = decorator(arg)(func)`

When you pass in the argument to the decorator, you are returning a completely new function (`multiply_x`) as the return value from the decorator `multiply` and replacing the identifier `sq` with it.

This function you just returned then takes the original function `sq` which now becomes the `f` parameter inside the inner function.

Now when you do `sq(n)` you actually call the inner `f_(n)`. This function returns `x` (the 3 you passed in as the argument to your decorator) times the result of calling the function `f` (which was the original `sq` function)

I hope this somewhat clears things up